# MySQL - how to define new collation without changing the default one in /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml

Tags: mysql, vps, collation, charset

I have a VPS hosting on namecheap, and i have defined a new collation "utf8_arabic_ci" in /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml and it is working perfectly. But the problem is when the hosting provider perform a cPanel update, the file is reverted to its default state and my changes gone. This lead to stop mysql service due to collation not defined.
Is there anyway to add an external collation and import it somewhere or defined a new charsets file and overwrite the default one without being affected later after update? like for example i put it in http://MYDOMAIN/charsets/Index.xml

Thank you

I don't have root access to the VPS hosting, but the hosting provider do whatever i ask him to do, or i can ask for full access to VPS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's a reason for "cheap" to be in their name?

Comment: What version of MySQL was it before; what version after the upgrade?

Comment: Enlighten me...  How does your `utf8_arabic_ci` differ from `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_unicode_520_ci`?

Comment: @RickJames You have characters which are considered the same in Arabic (like Alef 'ا' and Alef with Hamza 'أ'), but these are two different characters in database systems. When you try to make a search function in your website, for example, you want to ignore the differences between these characters. The use of case-insensitive collation like utf8_unicode_ci won’t solve the problem.

Comment: @RickJames the mysql version didn't change, i am not sure what the cpanel update do, but the result is that i am loosing the changes on the Index.xml file on every update, and when i re-add my custom collation it work again. I want something that don't be affected on every cpanel update

Comment: Meanwhile, suggest you post a feature request (for an Arabic collation) at bugs.mysql.com .